# Protocol buffers on Game Consoles

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, xbox360, playstation3

Have anyone tried google protocol buffers on game consoles? I'm more interested in High End consoles such as PS3 or Xbox360 than handheld systems.

Things I'm interested in hearing about are:

- Does it compile nicely out of the box or do you need to deal with the protobuf compiler to get the generated code right right?
- Are there any controversial library dependencies that may cause problems?
- Are there any concerns about generating too much code making the code size of the game explode?

I'm thinking of using it in a C++ environment. Feel free to add more concerns you think I should consider. I'm not only looking for problems, success stories are just as interesting.

Comment: You might try asking this on [gamedev](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

1. It compiles pretty cleanly. You just need to put the protobuf headers in your include path and then link with the libraries. I haven't had any strange warnings from it either, which happens sometimes with generated code.
2. I do not believe there are any dependencies. I was able to get it compiling on Windows, Linux, and Mac OS X.
3. The generated files are pretty nasty, but I haven't had any problems with them adding to the code size, or drastically increasing build times.

I have been able to easily integrate protobuf with other networking libraries (such as POCO). My experience was pretty positive, but then it was just a test project, nothing for production.